# Is it possible to play one sound through USB headphones while playing another sound through Bluetooth?

Tags: sound, 16.10

Imagine an office chillin' on a Friday. There are some Friday slow-jams goin' on.

Let's say I want to set the groovy shared office playlist playing on our Bluetooth speaker but have to occasionally join a wee cybermeeting and want to use my USB headphones for that without disrupting the sweets beats on the Bluetooth.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should be able to set the output for each application, via the audio properties of the volume control next to your clock. While the application is running, open the audio properties window and go to the applications tab. While it's playing, you should be able to set the output device. Maybe that'll point you in the right direction. I'm on my phone so can't provide a more comprehensive answer, sorry. :)